# Convert CCITT Group 3 1-Dimensional TIFF to PDF using iText in Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext, tiff

I am experiencing an EOF Exception as follows when attempting to read tiff files using iText 5.5.10

```
ExceptionConverter: java.io.EOFException
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.readFully(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:249)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.readFully(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:241)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.TiffImage.getTiffImage(TiffImage.java:209)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.TiffImage.getTiffImage(TiffImage.java:314)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.TiffImage.getTiffImage(TiffImage.java:302)
at com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(Image.java:428)
at com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(Image.java:374)
at TiffToPdf.main(TiffToPdf.java:137)
```

The code I am using is:

```
    byte[] data = null;
    Image img = null;
    try {
        data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("tiff.tif"));
        img = Image.getInstance(data, true);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have tried skipping the Image step and using the TiffImage class explicitly but I experience the same error.

```
    byte[] data = null;
    Image img = null;
    try {
        data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("tiff.tif"));
        RandomAccessSourceFactory factory = new RandomAccessSourceFactory();
        RandomAccessSource fileBytes = factory.createSource(data);
        RandomAccessFileOrArray s = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(fileBytes);
        img = TiffImage.getTiffImage(s, true, 1, true);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I noticed that there are 2 classes within iText called TIFFFaxDecompressor and TIFFFaxDecoder but I haven't been able to find any resources online on how to use them.

Comment: i am not getting any EOF exception with your code, can you post your tif image ?

Comment: Here is an example file that we are having trouble with https://file.town/download/27pc2stvxlfgk06jdek9raouj

Answer (score 1):

with your given tiff image, the following code does worked for me i.e., converted to pdf successfully.

```
    byte[] data = null;
    com.itextpdf.text.Image img = null;
    try {
        //System.out.println(Paths.get("src/main/resources/tiff.tif"));
        data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/main/resources/file.tif"));
        RandomAccessSourceFactory factory = new RandomAccessSourceFactory();
        RandomAccessSource fileBytes = factory.createSource(data);
        RandomAccessFileOrArray s = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(fileBytes);

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("src/main/resources/destination.pdf"));
        document.open();
        int pages = TiffImage.getNumberOfPages(s);
        Image image;
        for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {
            image = TiffImage.getTiffImage(s, i);
            Rectangle pageSize = new Rectangle(image.getWidth(),
                    image.getHeight());
            document.setPageSize(pageSize);
            document.newPage();
            document.add(image);
        }
        document.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I will try this first thing tomorrow morning when I get back into the office and get back to you with the results.  Thank you for taking the time to code out your solution.

Comment: Hey Sasi, I have been testing your code against some other TIFF files that we have been having trouble with and I came across this file that does not work.  Would you be able to take a look at it?

https://file.town/download/m4pdybysikndvm1kstd9cwhst

Comment: is it worked for the 1st file you posted? and are you getting EOF Exception for the second file?

Comment: Your code worked for the first file that was posted on my question, however the file that I posted on your answer still receives the EOF Exception.

Comment: it does appears the tiff's are truncated where itext is choking up on.Itext doesn't guarantee it will work for every tiff.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix the TIFFs? We have quite a few of these that we are experiencing these same kind of issues with.

Comment: check [this](http://www.paulzepernick.com/java/java-apache-pdfbox-convert-multipage-tiff-to-pdf/)